# Rewriting URLs that may or may not contain multiple slashes

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to form an URL rewrite rule that will handle URLs such as `mysite.com/categoryName/` and `mysite.com/categoryName/productName/`, routing them to seperate handlers.  In my .htaccess file, if I use:

```
RewriteRule shop/(.*^/)/$ view.php?mode=category&id=$1
RewriteRule shop/(.*)/(.*)/$ view.php?mode=product&id=$2
```

the product pages rewrite correctly, but the category URLs throw a 400. If I use:

```
RewriteRule shop/(.*[^/])/$ view.php?mode=category&id=$1
RewriteRule shop/(.*)/(.*)/$ view.php?mode=product&id=$2
```

the reverse happens (category pages show, but 400s on product pages).

I can't tell if this is an issue with my RegEx (most likely), the fact that some URLs have to be checked by both rules, or perhaps if there might be a way to do both rewrites with a single rule. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dots `.` is typically a bad sign of non-explicit intention and can be confusing.  Also, it's being greedy, so that adds to the confusion.  Instead, use something like you sorta have in your second example...

`([^/]+)` which means "everything that is NOT in the negated character-class `[^...]`, which is only the slash in this case.  Repeated infinite times, required (I suggest required `+` for URLs):

```
RewriteRule shop/([^/]+)/$ view.php?mode=category&id=$1
RewriteRule shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ view.php?mode=product&id=$2
```

I'd also see possible issues with however you're handling Categories when viewing rewriting the product rules.  To be 100% sure, you should handle it something like this:

```
RewriteRule shop/([^/]+)/$ view.php?category=$1
RewriteRule shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ view.php?category=$1&product=$2
```

But that's off-topic perhaps.

Comment: Works like a champ! Thanks so much. And, actually, after mulling it over for a while, I have decided to utilize your suggestion on the rewrite of the product URL to use the category as well. This will allow products to be added to multiple categories. Thanks for that, also. :-) I would upvote, but not enough rep, yet...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The only thing I wish for new or intermediate Regex-Writers to know is to never use the dot `.`.